# Characters count didn't count when page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating character count for textarea and the limit text in textarea is 140 characters. I have created function using javascript to count the characters in textarea. Below textarea, i have showed the characters left. The character will be count when i press key in textarea. When loading to that page, there are some values in that page, but the characters left didn't count. It will count when i put mouse in that textarea and press key. I want the characters left counted according to the value in textarea when page loading.

**Here is my code**

**1. Javascript**

```
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
  if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
    limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
  } else {
    limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
  }
}
```

**2. HTML & PHP**

```
$tweet = "Hello world.";
<form name='myform'>
<textarea style='margin-bottom:10px; width: 750px;' class='text_tweet'
  name='limitedtextarea' rows='5' maxlength='140'
  onKeyDown='limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,140);'
  onKeyUp='limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,140);'>".$tweet."
</textarea>
<br><font size='1'>(Maximum characters: 140)<br>
You have <input readonly type='text' name='countdown' size='3' value='140'> characters left.</font>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to check `textarea length` and show it in `countdown` when page loaded, better to `create one function and call it on body load` like:

**JavaScript:**

```
function bodyOnload(limitNum){
var tweet = document.forms['myform'].elements['limitedtextarea'].value;
document.forms['myform'].elements['countdown'].value = limitNum - tweet.length;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="bodyOnload(140)">
<form name='myform'>
<textarea style='margin-bottom:10px; width: 750px;' class='text_tweet'
  name='limitedtextarea' rows='5' maxlength='140'
  onKeyDown='limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,140);'
  onKeyUp='limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,140);'>Hello world.
</textarea>
<br><font size='1'>(Maximum characters: 140)<br>
You have <input readonly type='text' name='countdown' size='3' value='140'> characters left.</font>
    </form>
</body>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vnhra/)**</kbd>

Comment: @user2738520. It should work. What is not working? have you tried to debug with tools like Firebug for FF. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vnhra/

Answer (score 1):

You can just invoke the function on load, with the same arguments as you do on keydown.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var frm = document.getElementsByName('myform')[0];
    limitText(frm.limitedtextarea,frm.countdown , frm.countdown.value);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrpra/)**

But i would suggest you to get rid of the inline attributes and register events yourselves.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var limitcount = document.getElementsByName('countdown')[0],
        limitNum = 140;
   //Register the listener
    document.getElementsByName('limitedtextarea')[0].addEventListener('keydown', function () {
        if (this.value.length > limitNum) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        } else {
            limitcount.value = limitNum - this.value.length;
        }
    });

    //on load trigger the event
    dispatchEvent(document.getElementsByName('limitedtextarea')[0], "keydown");
}

function dispatchEvent(element, eventName) {
     if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(eventName, false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else element.fireEvent("on" + eventName);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWjcD/)**

Comment: @user2738520 This should work, if not try to drill down. place debug points inside the method etc and see if it is going in. Did you try the second approach i gave aswell?

Comment: i forget to tell you, there are more that one textarea (loop from database.).

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand this right, this is what you need.

This code will update the text inside the `<p>` every time you let go a key;

Also it has a starting value set, so when page loads it already tells the limit;

```
<textarea id="txt" onkeyup="count(140,\'txt\',\'msg\');"></textarea>
    <p id="msg">140</p>
    <script>
        function count(c,txtid,msgid){
        document.getElementById(msgid).innerText = c - document.getElementById(txtid).value.length;
        }
    </script>
```

Note that the string parameters are scaped but you can work that up just taking the slashes out.